# Mocking Services in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple form to save and then use MailKit to provide email notification, with xUnit and Moq used for unit testing. I'm having difficulty setting up the unit test and associated services. I have a workaround ('if' statement in the action method) to only test the core repo saving functionality without also testing the email service. If I take out the if statement, the unit test does not have access to the appropriate methods, such as setting the web root path. The error is a null exception. If I default this value, there are other errors, such as "no database provider being configured for DbContext."

Is there a more appropriate way to set a unit test of this sort up? Or is it wrong to set up a unit test to test both the Create() and email functionality because it violates the one-function unit testing rule?

Unit test:

```
 [Fact]
        public void Can_Create_New_Lesson()
        {
            //Arrange
            //create a mock repository
            Mock<IHostingEnvironment> mockEnv = new Mock<IHostingEnvironment>();
            Mock<ILessonRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<ILessonRepository>();
            Mock<UserManager<AppUser>> mockUsrMgr = GetMockUserManager();
            Mock<RoleManager<IdentityRole>> mockRoleMgr = GetMockRoleManager();
            var opts = new DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext>();
            Mock <AppIdentityDbContext> mockCtx = new Mock<AppIdentityDbContext>(opts);
            //create mock temporary data
            Mock<ITempDataDictionary> tempData = new Mock<ITempDataDictionary>();
            //create the controller
            LessonController target = new LessonController(mockRepo.Object, mockEnv.Object, mockUsrMgr.Object, mockRoleMgr.Object, mockCtx.Object)
            {
                TempData = tempData.Object
            };
            //create a lesson
            Lesson lesson = new Lesson { Title = "Unit Test", Domain= "Unit Test"};

            //Act
            //try to save the product using the Create method of the controller
            IActionResult result = target.Create(lesson);

            //Assert
            //check that the repository was called
            mockRepo.Verify(m => m.SaveLesson(lesson));
            //check the result type is a redirection to the List action method of the controller
            Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
            Assert.Equal("Success", (result as RedirectToActionResult).ActionName);
        }
```

The Create() action method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Lesson lesson)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.SaveLesson(lesson);

                //This IF statement is a workaround for the unit test
                //don't email users if the Title is "Unit Test"
                if (lesson.Title != "Unit Test")
                {
                    emailUsers(lesson);
                }

                TempData["message"] = $"{lesson.Title} has been saved";

                //show the user that the update was made successfully
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                //there is a problem with the data values
                return View(lesson);
            }
        }
```

Email function:

```
public void emailUsers(Lesson lesson)
{
    var webRoot = environment.WebRootPath;
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "email\\NewLessonSubmitted.txt");
    string message = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    string domain = lesson.Domain;
    IQueryable<AppUser> userList = GetUsersInRole(identityContext, domain); 

    //if there are users in that domain, send the email
    if (userList != null)
    {
        foreach (AppUser user in userList)
        {
            sendEmail(domain, message, user.Email);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've instead implemented the email service as a class, as pointed out by MotoSV. However, I'm still getting an error for "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext" The stack trace for the exception points to the following method:

```
public static IQueryable<AppUser> GetUsersInRole(AppIdentityDbContext db, string roleName)
        {
            if (db != null && roleName != null)
            {
                var roles = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == roleName);
                if (roles.Any())
                {
                    var roleId = roles.First().Id;
                    return from user in db.Users
                           where user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)
                           select user;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I have this constructor in my dbContext class:

```
public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }
```

EDIT: The solution (provided by MotoSV) was to:
1) Create an email service class with appropriate methods and
2) Install the appropriate Nuget package for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
3) mock the DbContext as:

```
var opts = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppIdentityDbContext>()
                  .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                  .Options;
            Mock<AppIdentityDbContext> mockCtx = new Mock<AppIdentityDbContext>(opts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at moving the code responsible for sending emails into it's own class. This class will implement an interface that can then be mocked in your test.

For example, create the interface and implementation:

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    void SendEmail(string to, string from, string body);
}

public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public void SendEmail(string to, string from string body) 
    {  
        ...
    }
}
```

The `EmailService` class will hold the functionality required to talk to MailKit. Then, register the `IEmailService` with .NET Core and add it to the constructor of your class:

```
public class LessonController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
    public LessonController(IEmailService service, ...) 
    { 
        _emailService = emailService;
    }

    public void emailUsers(Lessong lesson)
    {
        ...
        if(userList != null)        
        {
            foreach(...)
            {
                _emailService.Send(...);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

In your test create a mock and pass that into your constructor.

Comment: This is a much better approach, thank you. But I am still getting an error for "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext." causing the unit test to fail. I've added more code related to this in the question

Comment: Do you create a instance of the DbContext in your class? If so, you could either mock it or create an instance in your test using an InMemory database and pass that into the constructor.

Comment: This is what I use during unit tests: `new AppDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options);` I create this at the start of each test and pass the `AppDbContext` into the constructor of a class.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you should *never* do stuff like putting in conditionals in your code for the purpose of unit testing. If for no other reason, you're violating the entire point of unit testing, as your test access different code paths than what your users actually experience; you learn nothing by doing this.

Testing that the repo *actually* saves is a job for a repo test *not* an action test. Likewise with your mail service: ensuring that an email is actually sent should be a test on your mail service, not your action method.

Long and short, your test here should simply ensure that the appropriate actions are taken (i.e. repo save is hit and email service send is hit). As such, you can drop in simple mocks that merely have those methods available to be hit. You don't need to (and shouldn't) be establishing full connections to the DB/SMTP server, as at that point you're *integration* testing, not unit testing.

Comment: Thank you for providing clarity as to the "whys" of unit testing, as I am new to it. This was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your applications **send email class** constructor should take an "email provider" object that is a generic email abstraction based on an **IEmailProvider** interface, and/or also take a **IDataAccessProvider** implementation.

Now you can mock both of these interfaces in the test and pass them to the **send email class** to test just your implementation.